# File size of 0 when trying to upload file through selenium with ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ng-file-upload

I'm using version 12.01 of the excellent ng-file-upload and attempting to create an e2e test with protractor using Chrome 49.  I'm using `sendKeys` to path the file path, and I'm able to see the upload being triggered, but the file size in the

```
<button
        class="avatar-upload__button"
        ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
        ng-model='ngfFile'
        accept="image/*"
        ngf-max-size="14.5MB">
</button>
```

I'm able to see the file upload being called in this function:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = (file, errFiles) => {
}
```

But at this point `file.size` is 0, where when I run this manually, i get the correct size.  I wouldn't be too fussed about this except that the upload seems to be getting choked off/is not happening (presumably because the file information is bad).

My guess at this point is it is related to using this on a button rather than an `input[type="file"]`.  I'm going to start digging into ng-file-upload, but any suggestions/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew something smelled bad here because nobody else was having this problem.  I assembled the path incorrectly and the file did not exist.